# this Object on Error 'message' getter in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I am seeing different behavior in Chrome vs Firefox and Safari for this code:

```
var FancyError = function(x) { this.x = x; };
FancyError.prototype = new Error;

Object.defineProperties(FancyError.prototype, {
   'message': {
      'get': function(){ return "fancy:" + this.x; }
   }
});

new FancyError("hi") + '';
```

No errors are generated in strict mode. The error is caused by chrome calling the message getter with a different this object than expected.

Firefox/Safari output: `"Error: fancy:hi"`

Chrome output : `"Error: fancy:undefined"`

Any idea what is going on here?

**Versions Tested**

Chrome: 30.0.1599.69 OSX

Firefox: 24 OSX

Safari: 6.0.5 OSX

Comment: You'd better override `Error.prototype.toString` instead of the getter of `message`. That's more reliable, and in accordance with the specification. What you're doing at the moment has undefined behaviour.

Comment: True, I'm still curious why. In ECMA3 `Error.prototype.toString` is implementation defined, but not ECMA5. Looking at the ECMA5 spec for `Error.prototype.toString` (15.11.4.4), it calls internal `[[Get]]` on the error object with `'message'`.  `[[Get]]` (8.12.3) should get the `'message'` property and call the accessor with the current object.

Comment: @MattBierner I've filed a bug in V8: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely appears to be a bug in Chrome's `Error.prototype.toString`:

```
var FancyError = function(x) { this.x = x; };
FancyError.prototype = new Error;
FancyError.prototype.x = "I'm the prototype";

Object.defineProperties(FancyError.prototype, {
   'message': {
      'get': function(){ return "fancy:" + this.x; }
   }
});

var fe = new FancyError("I'm the instance");
```

With this setup in Chrome:

- `fe.message` produces `fancy:I'm the instance`
- `fe.toString()` produces `Error: fancy:I'm the prototype`

What happens in the first case is easy to understand:

1. `fe.message` prompts a call to `[[Get]]` on `fe` with the argument `"message"`
2. `[[Get]]` Step 1 gets the accessor descriptor set on `fe`'s prototype (since `fe` does't have it's own `message` property).
3. `[[Get]]` Step 6 calls the getter on the accessor descriptor, with `this` set as the *original object* that called `[[Get]]` (here, the `fe` object).

The second case is strange. It appears that `fe.toString()` performs the `[[Get]]` for `"message"` on the `Error` instance in `fe`'s prototype. This appears to be wrong, since Step 5 of `Error.prototype.toString` specifies getting the `message` from the `this` value in the `toString` function.

**EDIT**

I previously assumed that the problem was caused by `fe` having `Error` in its prototype chain. However, consider this case:

```
var FancyError = function(x) { this.x = x; };
FancyError.prototype.x = "I'm the prototype";

Object.defineProperties(FancyError.prototype, {
   'message': {
      'get': function(){ return "fancy:" + this.x; }
   }
});

fe = new FancyError("I'm the instance");
```

In this case:

- `fe.message` is `fancy:I'm the instance` as above
- `Error.prototype.toString.call(fe)` is `Error: fancy:I'm the prototype`

therefore, we must conclude that Chrome's `Error.prototype.toString` mistakenly uses the prototype that contains the getter as the `this` value of the `getter`, which appears to contradict the normal behavior of `[[Get]]` and/or Step 5 of `Error.prototype.toString`.

Comment: Indeed that seems to be what it does: https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/messages.js#1278